# showing two View object by addView()

Tags: java, android

I wrote the following code.But It can display only the **textView** object and It can not display draw object.What is the problem?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Draw draw;
    Cal cal;
    TextView textView;
    RelativeLayout linearLayout;
Canvas canvas;
 Paint paint;
    public void onCreate(Bundle s) {
        super.onCreate(s);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.t);
        cal = new Cal(this);
        cal.cal();

        textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setText("" + cal.result);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        draw = new Draw(this);
canvas = new Canvas();
        paint = new Paint();
        draw.d(canvas, paint);
        linearLayout.addView(draw);
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
    }}
```

**Draw.java**

```
public class Draw extends View {

public Draw(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public void d(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {

    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawCircle(120,120,40,paint);
    }
}
```

**Cal.java**

```
public class Cal extends View {
   public Cal(Context context){
        super(context);
    }
    public double result;
    double parameter = (Math.pow(40,2)) * 3.14;
    public void cal(){
        result = Math.sqrt(parameter);

    }
}
```

What is the problem?...................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You had to set the height and width of your custom view. And also the way you were drawing the custom view was not correct.**

I have updated your classes, you can run and test them.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Draw draw;
Cal cal;
TextView textView;
RelativeLayout linearLayout;
Canvas canvas;
Paint paint;

public void onCreate(Bundle s) {
    super.onCreate(s);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.t);
    cal = new Cal(this);
    cal.cal();

    textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textView.setText("" + cal.result);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    draw = new Draw(this);

    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(200, 200);
    draw.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    linearLayout.addView(draw);
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
}}
```

**AND**

```
public class Draw extends View {
Paint paint;

public Draw(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawCircle(120, 120, 40, paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should draw in `View.onDraw()` on the Canvas provided by the system, not create your own Canvas.

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Also, you should set the proper dimensions for your "Draw" view. By default it will have a size of zero.

Answer (score 0):

Check your activity_main layout file. Set width and height of linearlayout to match_parent. And also set orientation to vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Change you layout R.id.t from `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add view using index like,

```
linearLayout.addView(draw,0);
        linearLayout.addView(textView,1);
```